# How to pivot a Pandas Dataframe into the following (horizontal) form?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Column1 | Column2
-----------------
   A    |   1
   A    |   2
   B    |   3
   B    |   4
```

I want to produce the following:

```
Column3 | Column4 | Column5
---------------------------
   A    |    1    |    2
---------------------------
   B    |    3    |    4
---------------------------
```

I know the pd.melt() can be used to go from my desired df to the original.
How can I transform the current df into the desired?

Comment: Look at Q/A 10 in the dup link.

Comment: `df.set_index(['Column1', df.groupby('Column1').cumcount()]).unstack()`

Comment: Exact output with `df.set_index(['Column1', df.groupby('Column1').cumcount()]).unstack().set_axis(['Column4', 'Column5'], axis=1).rename_axis(index='Column3').reset_index()`